# Is "Should I...?" appropriate here?

Tags: ambiguity, conversation

> Joseph puts a gun to the man's head, and looks to Angelo.
>
> Joseph: Should I shoot him?

Joseph is basically asking: Do you want me to kill him? - Is that conveyed through "Should I shoot him?"? or does it more translate to "Do you think I should shoot him?"?

Comment: You are writing this story - it's up to you to decide what the characters mean by what they say!

Comment: [Does it translate more to x]

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how he emphasizes his question.
If he sounds confused/uncertain with emphasis on "should", then he is pondering whether he should indeed do this and asking for the other's opinion.
If he sounds direct/controlled, then it is like you say, "Do you want me to kill him?"

So, if you want that distinction without ambiguity, I'd use the examples that you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how Joseph conveys it. If you say:

> Joseph shouted: SHOULD I SHOOT HIM?

Then it basically means: Do you want me to kill him?

but you can also say:

> Joseph asked: Should/shall I shoot him

it gives another impression

Comment: Can you expand on what the impression is that the second conveys?

Comment: @mdewey  I think not a very different impression than the first, but a bit softer.